# Trouble with CDF on Mac OSX

Tags: cdf-format, html

My problem seems to be very strange.  I've created a CDF file and am trying to upload it to a Google site, and I've been almost completely successful!

My only problem is that I cannot correctly view/interact with the CDF on my Mac.  If I view in Safari, I cannot interact with the CDF, and if I use Firefox I can, but the CDF flashes near the top and bottom.  However, if I view the exact same webpage on my desktop (running Windows 7), everything works fine across Firefox and Chrome!

It seems that I've narrowed the issue down to spacing.  If I take my original `.nb` file and save it as a `.cdf`, I preserve the spacing that I inteded to have, but I encounter the website embedding issues.  However, if I run the "deploy as HTML" option, my spacing shrinks and becomes more compact, and my Mac browsers can handle the CDF.  Problem is, I want to keep the spacing.  Also, I am trying to give the embedded CDF a pixel size of 800x800.
Any ideas?

The two files can be downloaded from here:

- [Spaced webpage](https://sites.google.com/site/cdftestpage/not-shrunken)
- [Compact webpage](https://sites.google.com/site/cdftestpage/home)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is caused by an interaction between the embedding JavaScript and the *Page Zoom* feature in Safari. If you reset the page zoom to "Actual Size" by pressing `Command-0` (or from the `View` menu), it hopefully will allow you to interact with the controls again.

After that, it may even be possible to return to a larger zoom setting and still have the `CDF` work properly, because the display script may receive updated values for the available window size that it needs to calculate the offset between your mouse pointer and the controls.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, even though it didn't quite work.  However, I have figured out that the reason that the CDF is not working on Safari has to do with the CDF embedding box reaching the top of my browser.  So, I can interact just fine while there is some space between the top of my CDF "box" and the top of my browser, but as soon as it reaches the top, it stops responding.  Any ideas?